# autoconf AC_CHECK_HEADERS for C++11

Tags: debian, autoconf

I am trying to create a configure script using `autoconf`.  One important check is the presence of a specific header file.  This is typically very simple with the following line in my `configure.ac` file.

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS("CL/cl2.hpp")
```

However, some code within this header file requires C++11.  As such, after I run the resulting `./configure` I find the following error in the `config.log`.

```
configure:3166: checking CL/cl2.hpp usability
configure:3166: g++ -c -g -O2 conftest.cpp >&5
In file included from conftest.cpp:52:0:
/usr/include/CL/cl2.hpp:442: error #error Visual studio 2013 or another C++11-supported compiler required
```

Now I am using `Debian Stretch` and the g++ version is `5.2.1` so I know it supports C++11.  How can I use `autoconf` to create a `configure` file to check for this header file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the compiler option to enable the c++11 dialect in your CXXFLAGS variable.  For example, you can call:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 ./configure
```

This will cause all tests run by autoconf that use a c++ compiler to add `-std=c++11` into the tests (and iirc into the generated Makefile).

To do this within autotools, there is a macro [`AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html) that will test for c++11 support (optional or mandatory) and then set an appropriate compiler flag to enable that support in your build and tests.  Put this macro before your header checks and the header checks will be run with c++11 support.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.  Although I would add that I needed to install `autoconf-archive` to get the `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` macro.  A followup question, is this OS agnostic?  Would the resulting configure script work on a Mac or Windows system?

Comment: Also, interestingly the next line in the `config.log` checking for the `.hpp` file presence continues to not use the `-std=gnu++11` option resulting in a warning.  Not sure why.